# Getting Twitter Username using Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

**Im Trying to get a users twitter link using Firebase Auth but only manage to get his displayname, is there a specific way of getting access to it through firebase**

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      document.getElementById('player-name-header').innerHTML = 'Book Your Game ' + user.displayName;
      document.title = user.displayName + " CAST | Fingerprint ZA"
      console.log(user)
      displayGames();
    } else {
      // No user is signed in.
        window.location.assign('./cast-login');
    }
  });
```